# RS232 ISP programming

Tags: rs232, isp

I have a saleae digital analyzer and i am using it to listen to on a ISP programmer. (not to steal someone's code, but to build my own programmer). It only has two wires (GND & SDA)

The data just seems to stream this:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
and so forth until 255 & it starts again.

Does anyone know how it might be sending the data?

Thanks,

Cameron.

Comment: I believe you are not interpreting the signal properly. What kind of device you are talking about (BTW, cloning programmers are sometimes considered to be illegal as well)?

Comment: It's a megawin (china) ISP programmer.

Comment: The data is very consistence.

Comment: The datasheet for your microcontroller should include the protocol for talking to the ISP, or you should be able to Google for it.

Comment: It doesn't say much: http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/megawin/mpc82g516a_a4.pdf

Comment: "It doesn't say much" Really??!!??? Did you read section 20.2??? Quoting from that section "For the user who wants to design his own ISP operation, this section includes all the necesary technical information for ISP". You have everything you need there

Comment: @Kvegaoro Operation, as in the code that lives in the controller for ISP. Not as in "Hey, here's our signal layout", such as the mainstream vendors usually supply, be it sometimes rather cryptic.

Comment: Kvegaoro, yes, I see the SFR!!!!! But I do not have access to change the ISP code on the chip. If I did I could write my own ISP. However, I do not!?!?!?!?

Comment: Please provide about which controller we are talking about, LPC?

Answer (score 1):

I'd call this a you get what you pay for situation. Considering most mainstream brands already don't charge that much, I hope this was a very cheap chip & tool.

The point is, they label it as SDA on the programmer, but DTA on the chip. Other words: It's not going to be standard. It'll be some fixed-timing or auto-baud-enabled scheme sending out data into the controller. Yet whole other words: Not likely anybody here will know what it sends, unless they also tried to reverse engineer something that should be cheap enough not to want to.

Point of interest, though, the datasheet does state you can also use/trigger/whatever the ISP procedure through standard serial port (careful of the level conversion!), but it seems like at least you're stuck with their (or Keil's?) PC software.

If you want to do it all yourself, you are going to probably end up happier sticking to any of the other brands supplying 8051 compatible chips with an established name in microcomputing. Not in the least because they will likely have documents about the signals and communications standards, because they want everyone to want to use their chips, so an open-source community for all the Linux'ers and Hobbyists is very welcome to them.

Anyway, I'm happy to delete this, if (hopefully when) I'm proven wrong.